# Prove that if $AB = 0$, then rank(A) + rank(B) ≤ p

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be an $m \times$ n matrix and $B$ be an $n \times p$ matrix.

I understand that since $AB=0$, the column space of $B$ is contained within the nullspace of $A$. Does this mean that $\operatorname{rank}(B) \leq  \operatorname{nullity}(A)$?

How do I proceed to show that $\operatorname{rank}(A)  + \operatorname{rank}(B) \leq p$ ?

Comment: Hint: Yes. Then use a theorem about rank + nullity. Do you know it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may indeed deduce that the rank of $B$ is less than or equal to the nullity of $A$.

From there, simply apply the rank-nullity theorem (AKA dimension theorem).

---

**Counterexample to question as stated:**
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0}
,\quad
B = \pmatrix{1\\0\\0}
$$
$B$ is $3 \times 1$ and $AB = 0$, but $\operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B) = 3 > 1$.

Comment: I do know the rank-nullity theorem. However,  from rank(B)≤nullity(A), adding rank(A) to both sides, applying the rank-nullity theorem, I arrive at rank(A) + rank(B) ≤ n. I can't seem to arrive at ≤ p.

Comment: Hmmm that was an oversight on my part... there could be a typo in the question.

Comment: In fact, the statement to be proved is incorrect as stated.  I'll edit in a counterexample.

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: I just clarified and yes it is a typo. So much for spending hours and hours racking my brain over this. Thank you for helping.